# Pyspark map a function to two array type

Tags: function, dictionary, pyspark

I am quite new to Pyspark, here is what I try to do, below is the table, type is `ArrayType(DoubleType), ArrayType(DecimalType)`

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| [1,2] | [2,4] |
| [1,2,4] | [1,3,3] |

What I want to do is treat A and B as np.array, then pass a function to do calculation.

```
def func(row):
   a = row.A
   b = row.B
   res = some-function(a,b)
   return res
```

What I am trying now is

```
res = a.rdd.map(func)
resDF = res.toDF(res)
resDF.show()
```

But I am receiving the following error, could someone guide me a bit here? Thank you.

```
TypeError: schema should be StructType or list or None, but got: PythonRDD[167] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:53
```

Comment: How does this work `[1,2,4] * [1,3]`?

Comment: @pltc, typo, should have the same length.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas_udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf)

###### sample data

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ([1,2], [2,4]),
    ([1,2,4], [1,3,3]),
], 'a array<int>, b array<int>')
df.show()

+---------+---------+
|a        |b        |
+---------+---------+
|[1, 2]   |[2, 4]   |
|[1, 2, 4]|[1, 3, 3]|
+---------+---------+
```

###### create new column with `pandas_udf`

```py
@F.pandas_udf("array<int>")
def func(a, b):
    return a * b

df.withColumn('c', func('a', 'b')).show()
+---------+---------+----------+
|        a|        b|         c|
+---------+---------+----------+
|   [1, 2]|   [2, 4]|    [2, 8]|
|[1, 2, 4]|[1, 3, 3]|[1, 6, 12]|
+---------+---------+----------+
```